# Not Opted in Status updates Android vs iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

We have implemented MobilePush in Android and iOS.

Upon app install and acceptance (on iOS) of notification consent the SFMC contact is set as "Opted in"

On iOS when a user toggles off push notifications SFMC Status is immediately updated "Not Opted in"

On Android toggling off the notification setting the contact Status remains "Opted in"

Otherwise all behavior is as expected.

Is this an issue or is it a limitation in Android? The documentation is not clear on whether the Opted in status should update immediately in SFMC or after failed notification delivery attempts https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_opt_outs.htm&type=5

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK does not interrogate push preferences set by the user and the user will remain opted-in to push notifications at the server until `disablePush` is called by your application.  This is handled differently on iOS because it's a hard "permission" for that platform and consent must be expressly granted.